# Get the id of input field using php and set it in a variable

Tags: php, html

I am using clone form js to duplicate the form element where I have the following code:

```html
<div class="span3 unit">
  <input id="design" class="hidden">
  <a href="{{ url('/vendor/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&field_id=design&descending=1&sort_by=date&lang=undefined&akey=061e0de5b8d667cbb7548b551420eb821075e7a6') }}" class="btn iframe-btn btn-primary" type="button">
    <i class="icofont icofont-ui-image"></i> Choose
  </a>
  <div class="input">
    <input id="holderdesign" class="form-control" name="title">
  </div>
</div>
```

When I duplicate the above code my code becomes like the following:

```html
<div class="span3 unit">
  <input id="design1" class="hidden">
  <span class="input-group-btn">                                                                                          
            <a href="{{ url('/vendor/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&field_id=design&descending=1&sort_by=date&lang=undefined&akey=061e0de5b8d667cbb7548b551420eb821075e7a6') }}" class="btn iframe-btn btn-primary" type="button">
               <i class="icofont icofont-ui-image"></i> Choose
            </a>
        </span>
  <div class="input">
    <input id="holderdesign1" class="form-control" name="title">
  </div>
```

I want to get the id of hidden input in a variable so that I can pass that variable in the field_id parameter:

```
url('/vendor/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&field_id=design&descending=1&sort_by=date&lang=undefined&akey=061e0de5b8d667cbb7548b551420eb821075e7a6')
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

The reason I was trying to get the id of input field was to insert value. I will have the following output when I duplicate the field.

[image]

And I have the following code to insert the value in the input and holder field.

```
function responsive_filemanager_callback(field_id){
        var url=jQuery('#'+field_id).val();
        $("#holderdesign").attr("src",url);
        $('#design').val(url.replace('https://local.com',''));
    }
```

I tried increasing the value of id like this but it did not work.

```
let i = 0;
    $('#designClone').on('click', function () {
        i++;
        function responsive_filemanager_callback(field_id){
            var url=jQuery('#'+field_id).val();
            $("#holderdesign"+i).attr("src",url);
            $('#design'+i).val(url.replace('https://local.com',''));
        }
    })
```

Comment: You are nesting an input into another input. So your question is a bit unclear, of what values you want to put where.

Comment: @Mario I believe input are self closing in normal doctypes

Comment: @mplungjan Yes!

Comment: uh, indeed, my bad - nevermind. But I dont see a hidden value in the code to pass into the field_id.

Comment: @Mario I want design1 in a variable if it is possible.

Comment: ah, ok, thats not the value, thats the id. Can you put your "clone-script" into the question. Than I can edit it to achieve that.

Comment: @Mario Please look at the question I have edited it.

Comment: Sorry, there is no javascript - just a link (href) to dialog.php with some variables. 
Without the javascript part, this wont work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203895/discussion-between-alisha-and-mario).

Comment: @Alisha Just please post a [mcve], for example using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Also show where you want to put `url('/vendor/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&field_id=design&descending=1&sort_by=date&lang=undefined&akey=061e0de5b8d667cbb7548b551420eb821075e7a6')` which looks like a background image css statement

Comment: For this you need javascript